# Unable to change time format from 16:00:00 to 4 pm

Tags: ios, iphone, datetime, xcode6

Im receiving time data from a webservice. The values look like this:

```
01:00:00
16:00:00
```

I need to change the time format to **1 am** and **4 pm** respectively. For this I have used this code which doesn't work:

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = (NSDate *)obj[@"open_time"];
```

at this step, date object has **01:00:00** stored. I checked.

Then:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

and str is nil. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check, It work for me.Try this and let me know..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"01:00:00"];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h a"];
[dateFormat setAMSymbol:@"AM"];
[dateFormat setPMSymbol:@"PM"];
NSString *str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```